# Ajax Jquery Call throws 401 Exception

Tags: asp.net, json.net, http-status-code-401, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

recently, while implementing Ajax Jquery on one the my site, throw strange 401 UnAuthorised error, the strange thing in it is i am using forms authentication and the user is also logged in, but still its throwing the UnAuthorised error, i am using DNN CMS System

can anyone help me with the above probblem.
below is the console from Firebug

http://guitarplayer.com/401Error.png

i am able to post the data, but unauthorised error while returning results.

Comment: Your link appears to be broken.  404 error.

Comment: i have added the image for the firebug console.. if you are not able to see the image, below is the reponse from server.
POST GetPollDetails (this is the WebMethod)----  401 Unauthorised

Comment: @Abbas: What is the actual request going to that resource?  Debug on the server-side to try and determine why it's returning that error.  Where is it actually happening and for what purpose?  We can't see anything about your server from here.

Comment: hi david, actually i have a simple ajax call which POST to server, and  gets the result from SERVER, the problem is i am getting 401 while server returns with response, i have everything fine in web.config too and also i am logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its done, actually the problem was, i have missed the Class file including web method, but the strange thing was, Ajax Jquery should have replied me with 404 file not found, but instead it throws unauthorised access. anyways thanks guys for helping me

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to your CMS system using CSRF protection.  In order to POST, you will need to include CSRF details along with your post.

This same problem occurs in Rails apps.  If you use POST without including CSRF information, the session gets reset and the login page is returned.  This is a protection mechanism.

Comment: Hi Alfred, actually i am already using the Ajax Jquery on another page on the same site, same CMS System, and there its working fine, or can you tell how can i include CSRF inside Ajax POST

Comment: Hey Abbas,  I did a quick search for CSRF info on DNN and it appears that DNN does not include CSRF protection by default, so it appears my answer isn't applicable.  Sorry! :)

Comment: thats fine, is there any thing else i could try to resolve this.